# Error create Python virtual Environment win 10

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create python virtual environment for a project,Python 3.7.2, win 10 using command:

```
C:\Users\STAR WARE\Documents\Python\Tricks book>python -m venv venv
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\STAR WARE\\Documents\\Python\\Tricks book\\foo\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

Note I used Administrator Command Prompt

Comment: Hi Khaled, firstly do you venv installed? Also have you tried using something like anaconda, it makes running and installing python packages easier in Windows

Comment: I've anaconda installed, besides I've another Python 3.7.2 installed and added to the path environment. I use anaconda for Notebook, and my favorite editor is Sublime Text uses the python on the path.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried instead 'virtualenv' in place of 'python -m venv' and it worked as below:

```
C:\Users\STAR WARE\Documents\Python\Tricks book>python -m venv virt1
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\STAR WARE\\Documents\\Python\\Tricks book\\virt1\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.

C:\Users\STAR WARE\Documents\Python\Tricks book>pip install virtualenv

Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\star ware\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (16.4.3)

C:\Users\STAR WARE\Documents\Python\Tricks book>virtualenv virt2
Using base prefix 'c:\\users\\star ware\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37'
New python executable in C:\Users\STARWA~1\DOCUME~1\Python\TRICKS~1\virt2\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```