# Unable to create process using '...\python.exe' | error in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm unable to use python within the virtual environment. Python works fine outside of the virtual environment. I'm using Python 3.10.2

I keep on getting the error below when trying to run any python commands.

```
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
```

It might be relevant to mention that I was unable to create the virtual environment through the 'python -m venv env' command. Error generated was

```
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python Projects\\PDFtoText\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.
```

I had to add 'without-pip' to the end of the command to create the virtual environment. Weird thing is, I was able to use pip within the virtual environment without having to manually install it.

The path to python is in the environmental variables.

I tried reinstalling python but that did not help.

Lastly, all these errors started occurring after I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2022.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Short answer, I bet you have a space in your Window's account name (say `Your Account` is where your account is saved so you have `C:\Users\Your Account` folder, and there is also a text file `C:\Users\Your` ("Your" being the first part of your user name). MSVS2022 (maybe earlier versions, too) is known to leave this log file which exposes a bug in Python venv's python launcher. Delete this text file, and your problem should be solved.

See [my question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039131) for more details.

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much! Sadly, I'm new so I cannot upvote your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear! I think you can still accept my answer on your own question (that is, the answer we are commenting on) Appreciate it if you would

Comment: god bless, i've been searching forever

Comment: you are an absolute hero I've been looking everywhere for a solution to this problem

Comment: Scratching my head as to why my 3.9.x virtualenv wasn't working but my 3.10.x was fine. This was why - I had just installed Microsoft c++ build tools. I had more than one text file with a name beginning "Your" in my C:\Users directory.