# In pycharm showing Unable to create process using

Tags: python, pycharm

C:\Users\MERIN\PycharmProjects\Python_Projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\MERIN\PycharmProjects\Python_Projects\programs.py
Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\MERIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe" C:\Users\MERIN\PycharmProjects\Python_Projects\programs.py'

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I am new so I can not add a comment to your question. I hope this [quesition page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043378/unable-to-create-process-using-python-exe-error-in-virtual-environment) could help you.